# Indent in 'enumerate' after the '\item[·]'

Tags: indentation, enumerate, itemize

I'm trying to have a list as

```
  This is important because
  \begin{enumerate}
  \item[a)] \quad this,
  \item[b)] \quad this other and,
  \item[c)] \quad obviously this.
  \end{enumerate}
```

But all the packages that I have seen manages the indent space before the item, and I'm looking for an indent after the item. I could use '\quad' but it doesn't work if the text has more than one line. If someone could say me what is the package or code that I need I would be very grateful. I will appreciate any help or advice. Thanks.

Comment: you don't need any package (but you could use enumitem or even enumerate packages, just define the label to be `\alph{enumi})\quad`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suppose this is more or less what you want? I played with `\labelsep` and `leftmargin` via `enumitem`:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{ebgaramond}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[label = \alph*), wide, labelsep = 1em, leftmargin =*]
  \item She very imprudently married the Barber: and
  \item there were present the Picninnies, and
  \item the Joblillies, and the Garyulies, and the great Panjandrum himself, with the little round button at top.
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Bernard!!  (I think is not work if someone use '\\' in the sentence, Is it?).

Comment: @hllspwn: Which sentence?